# Uncertainty about BRK instruction behavior

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm64

I have some confusion about the BRK instruction and its behavior. I'm aware this generates a breakpoint interrupt - I assume this generates a SIGTRAP for that process?

Also, I've noted that BRK takes an immediate as an argument. How does this immediate change the behavior? Assuming I want to change the behavior of the "handler" based on where the interrupt occurred, does it make sense to handle this process locally, or does that only make sense from a ptracer who can see the values of the registers, PC, etc at the time of the SIGTRAP?

Comment: How the exception generated by `brk` is handled and what is done with the immediate is entirely up to your kernel. You might wanna add the `[linux]` tag to your question if you're looking for answers specific to Linux.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion Siguza - I've added that in now!